# Zabbix обрезает значения

Tags: linux, zabbix

Добрый день. Помогите разобраться. Хочу мониторить количество открытых файлов на удаленном сервере. делаю через юезр параметр = lsof | wc -l

По факту значение 456195 а в заббиксе получаю 4561. В графике пишет 4.56К.

Как получить полные значения? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В настройках элемента данных должно быть настроено так:

```
Тип информации: Числовой (целое положительное)
Тип данных: Десятичное
Хранение значения: Как есть
Отображение значения: Как есть
```

Comment: не то. нужно было в фронт энде добавить в blcklist значение единицы измерения. и тогда он перестает резать. Эта фича делается только через правку файла func.init.php

Comment: Очень странно, потому как я храню и отображаю большие числовые значения и не имел с этим проблем.